# Assign array values in R using function of indices

Tags: arrays, r

In Mathematica, I can make arrays using:

```
Table[f(x1, x2, ..., xn), {x1, v1}, {x2, v2}, ..., {xn, vn}]
```

Where `f` is any function, the `xi` are variables, and the corresponding `vi` are the vectors of values the variables take on.

If the `vi` have lengths `Li`, then the array is `L1xL2x...xLn`.

Is this functionality available in R with some built in function, or would I have to write my own program to do this?

Here's a function that I wrote which accomplishes what I want, but is there a built-in function that does this?

```
# Function definition
xapply <- function(fun,vecs){
 n <- length(vecs)
 dims <- sapply(vecs,length)
 prods <- c(1,cumprod(dims))
 ivecs <- vector(mode="list",length=n)
 for(i in seq(n)){
   ivecs[[i]] <- rep(rep(vecs[[i]],each=prods[i]),prods[n+1]/prods[i+1])
 }
 my.args <- c(fun,ivecs)
 return(array(do.call(mapply,my.args),dims))
}

# Example
v1=c(1,2,3,4)
v2=c(10,20,30,40,50)
v3=c(100,200,300)
v123=list(v1,v2,v3)
my.array1 <- xapply(function(x,y,z) x+y+z,v123)
my.array1
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate every possible v1 X v2 X ... X vn combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do this, demonstrating with your lambda and vector list `v123` as input:

```
array(do.call(function(x,y,z) x+y+z,unname(do.call(expand.grid,v123))),lapply(v123,length));
## , , 1
##
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]  111  121  131  141  151
## [2,]  112  122  132  142  152
## [3,]  113  123  133  143  153
## [4,]  114  124  134  144  154
##
## , , 2
##
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]  211  221  231  241  251
## [2,]  212  222  232  242  252
## [3,]  213  223  233  243  253
## [4,]  214  224  234  244  254
##
## , , 3
##
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]  311  321  331  341  351
## [2,]  312  322  332  342  352
## [3,]  313  323  333  343  353
## [4,]  314  324  334  344  354
##
identical(.Last.value,my.array1);
## [1] TRUE
```

The advantage of this line over an [`apply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html)- or [`Map()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html)-based solution is that it is vectorized. Only one call to the function is made.

First, [`expand.grid()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/expand.grid.html) is called via [`do.call()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html) with the vector list as the argument list. This produces a data.frame containing all possible combinations of the input vectors, one per row. We must then remove the automatically-generated column names from the data.frame by calling [`unname()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unname.html).

We can then pass the resulting unnamed data.frame as the argument list to the lambda, again invoked via `do.call()`. This works because data.frames are lists internally, with one list component per column, hence a data.frame is suitable for use as the list of arguments expected by `do.call()`. This also clarifies why the `unname()` call was needed; otherwise the lambda would be invoked with named arguments (the automatically-generated names being `Var1`, `Var2`, `Var3`) which would fail to bind to the parameters (`x`, `y`, `z`).

The result of the vectorized lambda call is an atomic vector. Since you want an array, we must wrap it in a call to [`array()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/array.html), and pass the appropriate dimensionality from the lengths of the input vectors via [`lapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html).

---

Also you may want to look into the [`outer()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/outer.html) function, which internally performs this kind of cartesian expansion, vectorized call, and dimensionality wrapping, but only for two input objects at a time.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so thoroughly! I'm new to R, and still learning the differences between data frames, lists, etc., and how to use them properly. Mathematica seemed so much easier; there were only lists.

Comment: That outer() function is exactly what I was looking for!  I wish that, instead of only making matrices, it took a variable number of vectors so that it could make arrays with more dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to apply a function to every combination of v1 ... vn, you could use `expand.grid` and `apply`:

```
x1 <- 1:5
x2 <- 1:10
x3 <- 8:10

# get the average
apply(expand.grid(x1,x2,x7), 1, FUN=mean)
# get the sum of squares
apply(expand.grid(x1,x2,x7), 1, FUN=function(i) sum(i^2))
```

If you instead have v1, ..., vn of equal length and you want to apply some function to corresponding entries, you can use `Map` (or `mapply`)

```
x1 <- 1:5
x2 <- 2:6
x3 <- 6:10
# get the sum of squares
Map(f=function(x,y,z) sum(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), x1, x2, x3)
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the expand.grid function. However, I'm trying to have the return object be an array A of dimensions L1xL2x...xLn, such that A[i1,i2,...,in] = f(i1,i2,...,in).

Comment: Does this mean e/xpand.grid, but the output is reorganized into an array of the vi dimensions?

Comment: Not exactly. Each row of expand.grid would be the inputs of the function for a certain element of the array. In fact, I'm sure that I can use expand.grid to greatly simplify my answer below! I'm just wondering if there's a built-in function for this already.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used rowSums (which takes hte place of your function) and used it on the result of expand.grid which tos the all-combinations expansions:

```
> array( rowSums( expand.grid(v123) ) , c(4,5,3) )
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  111  121  131  141  151
[2,]  112  122  132  142  152
[3,]  113  123  133  143  153
[4,]  114  124  134  144  154

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  211  221  231  241  251
[2,]  212  222  232  242  252
[3,]  213  223  233  243  253
[4,]  214  224  234  244  254

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  311  321  331  341  351
[2,]  312  322  332  342  352
[3,]  313  323  333  343  353
[4,]  314  324  334  344  354
```

You could use a less vectorised solution if the function didn't operate on a row by row basis. The `mapply` or `Reduce` functions would let you get the same vector:

```
> array( Reduce("+", expand.grid(v123) ) , c(4,5,3) )
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  111  121  131  141  151
[2,]  112  122  132  142  152
[3,]  113  123  133  143  153
[4,]  114  124  134  144  154

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  211  221  231  241  251
[2,]  212  222  232  242  252
[3,]  213  223  233  243  253
[4,]  214  224  234  244  254

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  311  321  331  341  351
[2,]  312  322  332  342  352
[3,]  313  323  333  343  353
[4,]  314  324  334  344  354
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that I figured out how to make my arrays using expand.grid(), but it's formatted slightly differently from my original question in that: (1) I'm entering the vectors individually, instead of in a list, (2) I'm defining the function using the variables x[1], x[2], etc., and (3) I'm assuming that I know the lengths of the vectors.  I still wish that outer() would just take an arbitrary number of arrays as arguments, because that function does exactly what I want, but only for two arrays.

```
array(apply(expand.grid(1:4,4:8,3:5), 1, function(x) 100*x[1]+10*x[2]+x[3]),c(4,5,3))
```